# What is the equivalent of math font used in old russian soviet books?

Tags: fonts, cyrillic, math-fonts, russian

I've been searching a lot about typesetting in USSR, and I couldn't find what is the font, that they used to typeset formulas.

The standard serif font in old soviet math books is called 'Literaturnaya' (https://www.paratype.com/fonts/pt/literaturnaya);

The standard sans-serif font is called 'Journal Sans' (https://www.paratype.com/fonts/pt/journal-sans);

But I have no idea what is the math font that was used in old russian/soviet math books.

Example is in these pictures:

[image]

Note that the integral sign and greek letters appear to be non-italic, while latin letters appear to be italic version of 'Literaturnaya'.

[image]

Also, the summation and square root symbols have high contrast.

Does anybody have an idea what is this font? Or what math font is most similar to this?

Comment: I have a couple of MIR books and I've seen several others. The font is not particularly appealing to me and the typesetting is quite irregular (for instance, in the last equation the summation sign is skew), but the books are always interesting. I'm not sure there's a matching math font. The placement of double integrals to cover the subscript is peculiar.

Comment: the letters can probably be taken from the text font, looking at the images one suspects that the distinctive integrals come from elsewhere, choosing a matching upright integral would probably make a reasonable style, the website you link to shows the font has an integral [as shown in their trial page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6eGC.png)